# How to find a probability of VIX moving from one price to another

Tags: programming, finance-mathematics, forecasting, vix

I asked a similar question on here with a bounty. I decided to modify the question to simplify what I am trying to do. Is there a package on MATLAB or some other tool where I can find the probability the VIX moves from one price to another? (i.e. the transition density). Is there a model I can work from? Does anyone have any recommendations in doing the latter above?

Comment: Mb. try the following two papers on VIX variance modelling (haven't read them myself).
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2028285 and https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3071762